# Prove that the inequality $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n < n$ holds for all $n \geq 3$

Tags: induction

First we need to prove the basis. If we let $n=3$, then $(1+ \frac{1}{3})^3 < 3$

$(\frac{3}{3}+ \frac{1}{3})^3 < 3$

$(\frac{4}{3})^3 < 3$

$(\frac{64}{27}) < 3$

The inequality statement is true

For $P(n), (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n < n$

We assume that $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n < n$ is true for $P(n+1)$

$(1+ \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} < n+1$

$(1+ \frac{1}{n+1})^{n})(1+ \frac{1}{n+1})^{1}) < n+1$

And then I'm stuck afterwards. I know that there are a variety of problems that use induction and they have different methods, but I only know the ones that are similar to $1+2+3+...+n = n+2$  or $7^n-8^n$ is divisible by $8$. Is there any technique to tackle this type of problem?

Comment: For this problem, use $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) < \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ to get the conclusion.

Comment: wait what... but that means that I have to take $P(n+1) < P(n)$ which is $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) < \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$, but what do I do next?

Comment: Remember to keep clearly separate in your mind the inequalities you have assumed or derived from the inequalities you're trying to obtain.

Comment: If I'm just plugging any number for $n$ I'll be able to see it, but I can't do that because that's not how a proof works.

Comment: In fact the much stronger bound $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n < 3$ holds for all $n$. So for $n ≥ 3$ this includes your inequality. But of course it takes a little more effort to prove.

Comment: At first I wanted the basis to be $n=4$ which leads to $\frac{625}{256}$ and that is less than 4...I don't understand why I couldn't use it because it is $n \geq 3$ right? so that means I can pick any number from 3 to whatever it ends up

Comment: No, you have to show it for all $n ≥ 3$. So If you start at $n=4$ you will have missed $n=3$. Induction means you prove it for a basis $3$ and then induce for any $n$ to the successor $n+1$. So you automatically get $3 ⇒ 4$, $4 ⇒ 5$, $5 ⇒ 6$ and so on.

Comment: alright. I have started for $n \geq 3$ and it is indeed less than 3, so the statement is true. ... for $P(n), (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n < n$ and $(1+ \frac{1}{n+1})^{n})(1+ \frac{1}{n+1})^{1}) < n+1$ for $P(n+1)$. What happens afterwards?

Comment: Is it not obvious that the function being increasing, equal to $2$ when $n=1$ and tending to $e=2.718281$ is < n for the given values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As canaaerus [points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669380/prove-that-the-inequality-1-frac1nn-n-holds-for-all-n-geq-3#comment1406819_669380) in the comments, we can in fact prove
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<3$$
In fact there's a proof of this that doesn't even use induction! I think it's worth writing down here since it's so simple (and it won't be giving away the answer to the homework problem, since the teacher presumably expects induction). We will binomially expand and use the following facts:
$${{n}\choose{r}}=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-r+1)}{r!}\leq\frac{n\cdot n\cdot\ldots\cdot n}{r!}=\frac{n^r}{r!}$$
and (for $r\geq1$)
$$\frac{1}{r!}=\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\ldots\cdot r}\leq\frac{1}{1\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot 2}=\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}$$
Here's the proof:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n&=\sum^{n}_{r=0}{{n}\choose{r}}\frac{1}{n^r}\\
&\leq\sum^{n}_{r=0}\frac{n^r}{r!}\frac{1}{n^r}\\
&=\sum^{n}_{r=0}\frac{1}{r!}\\
&=1+\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{r!}\\
&\leq1+\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}\\
&<1+\sum^{\infty}_{r=1}\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}\\
&=1+2=3
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I should've used that earlier! Using the Binomial Theorem makes this problem a whole lot easier.

Comment: Sure, but make sure you understand induction too! Otherwise I'll feel bad for doing you homework for you. Besides, induction is one of the most important ideas in mathematics.

Comment: I have been practicing induction problems like the ones I listed above which is $1+2+3+...+n = n+2$ and $7^n-8^n$ is divisible by $8$. This problem was a bit confusing because I did the basis and the equations holds true. I did $P(n)$ and that was easy, but the $P(n+1)$ part was very frustrating. I'm reading more about how to do the $P(n+1)$ because I want to learn how the whole process really works. I know there are a ton of different problems that use induction and not all of the steps are the same. I can't apply whatever I did earlier to this.

Comment: ...and that sucks because there is induction for geometric series ... induction for ... I don't what it's called but there was a fraction like this $\frac{1}{2*3} + \frac{1}{3*4}$

Answer (score 2):

The following inequality will be needed:
$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n} \Leftrightarrow 1+\frac{1}{n+1}<1+\frac{1}{n}\\
\Leftrightarrow \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$

From the induction hypothesis $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<n$ and the algebraic identity $\left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} = \left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n\left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$,

$$\Rightarrow\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n<n\\
\Leftrightarrow \left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n\left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)<n\left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
\Leftrightarrow\left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}<n+\frac{n}{n+1}$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: ok wait... ummmm so we have $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) < \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and that was spliced into this $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n} \Leftrightarrow 1+\frac{1}{n+1}<1+\frac{1}{n}\\
\Leftrightarrow \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ ..............so my question is that well did we factor out something to have it lead to the $(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^n < (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ ?

Comment: @usukidoll Are you asking how to get from $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) < \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ to $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n < \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$? You raise each side to the $n$-th power.

Comment: no. I'm asking for$ \frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n} \Leftrightarrow 1+\frac{1}{n+1}<1+\frac{1}{n}\\
\Leftrightarrow \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$

The top one with the $< \leftrightarrow < $ part.

Comment: @usukidoll: we add +1 on both sides there.

Comment: @usukidoll Take the inequality $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}$ and add $1$ to each side.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+1} + 1<\frac{1}{n} + 1$

Comment: @DavidH so for $\Rightarrow\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n<n\\
\Leftrightarrow \left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n\left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)<n\left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
\Leftrightarrow\left(1+ \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}<n+\frac{n}{n+1}$ it appears that you multiplied $(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})$ on both sides of the equation. So does this mean that I take the left side of the equation and simplify to obtain the result that is from the right side?

Answer (score 0):

This is the technique that I would use...

**Induction Step:** We assume $$ \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ k < k. $$

Multiplying both sides by "${\color{red}{something}}$" to get our desired outcome gives,

$$ \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ k {\color{red}{\frac{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} \right )^{k+1}}{\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ k}}} < k{\color{red}{\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)}}. $$

So all you need to show (for this inequality to hold) is

$$\frac{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} \right )^{k+1}}{\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ k} < \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right). $$

Which  is simple enough with some algebra.

Comment: This is not very helpful as a general approach as you don’t always get the assumption as a factor. You need to write down the induction hypothesis and look where you can apply the assumption.

Comment: Woops, similar to David H's response but hope it helps, let me know if you  want help with the algebra :)

Comment: I find that this actually works quite well for many inequality induction problems.

Comment: really? isn't that similar to the $1+2+3+...+n = n+2$ problem when after we do $P(n+1)$ we need to work on the left to achieve the right? Maybe algebra for the left side would work to get to the right side which is $(\frac{k+1}{k})$

Comment: Just be careful that your formulas don’t get unnecessary complicated.

Comment: yeah and then it would be a bigger mess

Comment: For induction we need to assume the formula is true for $n=k$ then show that the formula holds for $n=k+1$ I begin by assuming the formula holds for $n=k$ then multiply that formula by something(the inequality you have to show holds) to get the formula for $n=k+1$ (the second equation I wrote after simplification).

Comment: The inequality you need to show holds is very easy - after simplification you get $\frac{k^2 +2k}{k^2 +2k +1} <1 $ which is obviously true for $k\geq 3$.

Comment: yes it is .. but the $n=k+1$ is the messiest part of the whole problem. I can easily do the basis case and $n=k$, but it gets crazy afterwards.

Comment: If you can get from $\frac{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} \right )^{k+1}}{\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ k} < \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)$  to $\frac{k^2 +2k}{k^2 +2k +1} <1$ then you are done.

Comment: edit: I read this wrong... I couldn't cancel if I split the numerator for $\frac{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} \right )^{k+1}}{\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ k} $

Comment: Try dividing both sides of the inequality by $\frac{k+1}{k}$ then you will have $\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right) ^{k+1}$ on the denominator.

Comment: won't that produce two $\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right) ^{k+1}$?.... oh yeah but one will be just with the $k$ exponent and the other with just $1$ exponent

Comment: You should get $\frac{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} \right )^{k+1}}{\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ {k+1}}$

Comment: Haha yeah, but if you multiply them you will get $k+1$, like $x * x^k$ gives $x^{k+1}$

Comment: Anyway it's late here, if you're still stuck I'll get back to you tomorrow. Keep at it :)

Comment: divide by $\frac{k+1}{k}$ using this inequality $\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ k < k.$?

Comment: You don't need that, remember we are just showing that this inequality (in the red) is true. So that when we multiply the induction assumption by this inequality, we get the desired result (formula with n= k+1). We're just using (basic) algebra, don't need the induction assumption in this particular step.

Comment: alright so I just have to multiply and see if I get the final result which is the $\frac{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} \right )^{k+1}}{\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ k} < \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right).$

Comment: I was so CLOSE! the $1+ \frac{1}{k+1})^{k+1}$ is so annoying to get rid of. I've seen the $\frac{k^2+2k}{(x+1)^2} < 1$ but there was something that didn't cancel and that was $1+ \frac{1}{k+1})^{k+1}$

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as
$n
> (\frac{n+1}{n})^n
$
or
$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}
< 1
$.

This is true for
$n=3$,
since
$4^3 = 64$
and
$3^4 = 81$.

I will show that
$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}
$
is decreasing;
since this is less than one
for $n=3$,
this will show that
it is less than one
for all $n \ge 3$.

Showing this is decreasing
is the same as showing that
$\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}
> \frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+2}}
$.
Cross-multiplying,
this is the same as
$(n+1)^{2n+2}
>(n(n+2))^{n+1}
$
or
$(n^2+2n+1)^{n+1}
> (n^2+2n)^{n+1}
$
which is obviously true.

Answer (score -2):

Your approach is totally right. Look for a way to relate what you have at the end to the induction hypothesis. For example, it's certainly true that
$$
\bigg( 1 + \frac1{n+1} \bigg)^n < \bigg( 1 + \frac1{n} \bigg)^n.
$$
So if you replace the former by the latter in your last desired inequality, does that help you?

Comment: not really...sorry I'm kind of slow at this. And since there are so many induction problems out there, each one has a unique technique to tackle them

Comment: Given that your comment appeared less than one minute after my answer, I don't think slow has anything to do with it. Take some time to ponder it some more - that's where the learning comes from. (And it's not the technique that's different from problem to problem, just the specific ways of relating what you get to assume to what you want to prove.)

Comment: This is my first pure math analysis course. Of course I'll be slower than usual...I'm so used to computation only . So I have to replace something and...?